# Unable to connect to wifi in hp pavilion ab032tx

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp

I have hp ab032tx laptop, have erased windows and installed ubuntu 14.04.

Wifi is always out of range in my machine, now iam using internet by USB tethering for the past three days.

I googled much but none of the answers seems to work for me.

How to fix this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

go to **software&updates** and click on **Addition Drivers** there you can find your wifi drivers. before that update the ubuntu `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this link, I have Broadcam device in my hp machine too. 
[[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers][1])